# Error - Failed to add 'SAP-Connectivity-Authentication' header for on-premise connectivity

Tags: sap-cloud-platform, sap-cloud-sdk, sap-cloud-foundry

I am connecting an On-premise S/4 HANA with SAP Cloud Platform trial account.  I am using SAP Cloud SDK to fetch all Business Partners from S/4 HANA.

1. My Cloud Connector is set
2. My Destination at Sub-Account level is set and can ping to my on-premise system
3. My Service instances - XSUAA/Destination/Connectivity is set with the application

But I have the following error

**Failed to add 'SAP-Connectivity-Authentication' header for on-premise connectivity: no JWT bearer found in the 'Authorization' header of the request. Continuing without a header. Connecting to on-premise systems may not be possible**

The code which I am using is -

```
 final List<BusinessPartner> businessPartners =
                    new DefaultBusinessPartnerService()
                            .getAllBusinessPartner()
                            .select(BusinessPartner.BUSINESS_PARTNER)
                            .execute(destination);
```

It seems **AppRouter** is the recommended for Authorization and Access and hence I tried implementing one- but my approuter shows - **Not Found**

Approuter App -Name - approuter-demo
Below is the xs-app.json

```
{
  "routes": [
    {
      "source": "^/s4ext/(.*)",
      "target": "/s4ext/$1",
      "destination": "******"
    }
  ]
}
```

The Manifest file is as below:

```
---
applications:

- name: approuter-demo
  routes:
   - route: approuter-demo-*****trial.cfapps.eu10.hana.ondemand.com
  path: approuter
  memory: 128M
  env:
    TENANT_HOST_PATTERN: 'approuter-demo-(.*).cfapps.eu10.hana.ondemand.com'
    destinations: '[{"name":"******", "url" :"https://s4ext-***.cfapps.eu10.hana.ondemand.com", "forwardAuthToken": true }]'
  services:
    - xsuaa-demo
    - connectivity-demo
    - destination-demo
```

Kindly guide me. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by „I tried implementing one“?

Comment: And where does what show „not found“?

Comment: Not Found is shown when I open the approuter application. I expect the approuter should open my web application since I have mentioned target URL in the xs-app.json

Comment: Kindly tell us which SAP Cloud SDK version you're using and share us the stack trace of your exception.

Answer (score 0):

Your destination type might be wrong. The authorization header is set via the destination.
Try other types in sap cp -> connectivity.

Comment: we cannot use another type. it is an HTTP connectivity. Kindly suggest.

Comment: I can only guess. Provide some information on your destination. The type of authorisation was meant to be changed. Your error error says that a security token is not provided. The only configuration possibility is the destination. Otherwise you need to provide the authorization header manually. Bearer is a kind of security mechanism to connect to the system you read data, normally the destination is simply not configured correct even if the ping works.

Comment: `Description=TST destination
Type=HTTP
Authentication=BasicAuthentication
WebIDEUsage=odata_abap,ui5_execute_abap,dev_abap
Name=TST
WebIDEEnabled=true
URL=http\://XXXXX\:8001
ProxyType=OnPremise
sap-client=100
User=XXXX
WebIDESystem=TST`

Comment: The destination details are as above

Comment: Change basic auth with another mechanism by searching the right thing for your data source https://github.com/techpmsap/S4HC_Leonardo_PW2018/blob/master/Day1/Exercise_18/Exercise_18.md

Comment: I would say OAuth is the right, this is using bearer authentication

Comment: Great comment Emdee

Comment: Right, that was not precise. I mean the chosen destination type is not causing the error message mentioned in the question above.

Answer (score 0):

Reading your question again I can identify two issues:

- This error message in your log:

```
Failed to add 'SAP-Connectivity-Authentication' header for on-premise connectivity: no JWT bearer found in the 'Authorization' header of the request. Continuing without a header. Connecting to on-premise systems may not be possible
```

It may be that this error message is actually superfluous and hence indicating a problem which is actually none. In your case this header is possibly not necessary and the SAP Cloud SDK should not try to add it. But in any case, this will not influence the actual connection, so this error message is at most confusing, but not harmful in the sense of altering functionality.

Still, I am asking you to add the stack trace of this exception to your question to be very sure here.

- Your app router shows "Not Found":

Here I am missing more information. When does what exactly show "Not Found"? Is it that your browser cannot find your app router, or can your app router not find the target URL of the application?